# Giving a Text File for Variable Generation in Apache Velocity

Tags: java, code-generation, velocity

I am trying to understand how Apache Velocity works. I saw some examples on how it works, with taking a file as template and providing the variable generations to context object like:

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.init();
    /*  next, get the Template  */
    Template t = ve.getTemplate( "helloworld.vm" );
    /*  create a context and add data */
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("name", "World");
```

Is there any way to give a file to fill these variable generation inputs/data?

Comment: Please explain your question with some more details. How "to give a file to fill these variable"? I dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: I meant can I use a file to do what context.put("name", "World"); in one line like context.puts("input.txt"), rather than do it variable by variable?

Comment: Since a Context can be initialized with a map, you're free to build any map you want, by reading a file if you wish, and then create a Context with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was thinking to do that but wanted to know if there is a shorter solution. Will do the thing you suggested